# Can't get this phone number regex to work

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to use the phone number regex that this person [submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123666/1866690) but I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
<cfelseif NOT REFIND("^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$",contactphone) >
```

It's giving me an error around (\d+) at the end.
(I'm new to ColdFusion and using RegEx)

Comment: There is a pound sign `#` in your regular expression so you probably need to escape that for ColdFusion by doubling it up as `##`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ColdFusion `#` is used to output a string. If you're `cfelseif` is within `cfoutput` tags you need to escape the `#` by using `##`. Updating your regEx to the below format should solve your issue.

```
<cfelseif NOT REFIND("^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:##|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$",contactphone) >
```

Comment: @confusedStudent: If this answer solved your problem, you should indicate that to future readers by "accepting" it. See: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/accepted-answer)